# Trying to add string to ListView on button press

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I am trying to add the string to my ListView on a button press, but it isn't adding it. I'm assuming the issue is with refreshing the ListView, but I don't know exactly how to do that.

Comment: note: `listView.refresh()` is always (apart from very very infrequent corner-cases) the wrong thing to do - it's an indication that your setup is broken somehow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`FXCollections.observableArrayList(...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList(E...)) creates a new observable list and adds the elements provided to it. If you pass an array here, the elements of the array will be copied to the new list, and there will no longer be any connection between the array and the observable list, so subsequent changes to the array will not be reflected in the observable list.

All you need to do here is change the backing list directly. It's not really clear from your code what you intend to do: your array has one element in it, and you iterate through the array (i.e. just once) changing all the elements (there's only one) to `"k"`.

So the equivalent of this, but modifying the list, would just be

```
addButton.setOnAction(e-> {
    lv.getItems().set(0, "k");
});
```

The title of your question says you want to *add* and element to the list view, which you would do with

```
addButton.setOnAction(e-> {
    lv.getItems().add("k");
});
```

Comment: Wonderful thank you. That worked exactly as intended.